Visual Studio update broke R integration?
After VS Code installed an update yesterday (2024-12-11), it doesn't cooperate with R anymore.
When selecting code and trying to run it: command r.runSelection not found
When running code from source: command r.runSource not found
Any ideas on how to fix this?

did you check that the R version is the same? if it updated from 4.x to 4.y, you need to install the languageserver package for the current version

I didn't change R (still 4.4.0). When VSCode updated to 1.96.0, it broke the R integration.

maybe reinstall the R extension in VSCode
